# Shields File Containing Shield Images

Tags: shapefile, tilemill

Is there any file that contains already made shield images that are frequently used and comes with the installation of TileMill, or is there any page I can download it from. Link would be appreiciated. Specifically, I need some already made images of shields for highway labels and house numbers.

Comment: Never used TileMill before but found some shield images for highways which might be of use? They're from the [Looseleaf style](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-looseleaf.tm2/tree/master/img/shield).

Comment: Most welcome buddy! Hope you find more of what you're looking for :)